# Numbers a, b and c form an arithmetic sequence, and they are positive integer, a < b < c

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Numbers $a, b, c$ form an arithmetic sequence, and they are positive integers, $a < b < c.$

Let $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$.

There are two distinct real numbers $r, s,$ satisfy $f(r) = s, \; f(s) = r.$

If $rs = 2017$, determine the smallest value of $a.$

How can I start this question?

Comment: You could write $b$ as $a+d$, $c$ as $a+2d$ and $r=\frac {2017}s$

Comment: I got r = 2017 / s = 2017 / f(r) = 2017 / ar^2+br+c = 2017 /(ar^2+ar+rd+a+2d) what can I do next?

Answer (score 1):

You have the equations
$$ar^2+br+c=s$$
$$as^2+bs+c=r$$ and
$$b=\frac{c+a}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I tried.

$$f (x)=ax^2+bx+c$$

$$a,b,c $$ are in A.P.

Now, rewriting terms in 2 variables
Common difference = d

$$b=a+d $$ , $$c=a+2d $$

From the given conditions, we get

$$as^2+bs+c=r $$

And

$$ar^2+br+c=s $$

Try out subtraction, we get

$$a (s+r)+a+d=-1$$

Here's where I'm leaving any process further.

Hint for further procedure :

$$• d>0$$
• use A.M. G.M inequality.

Comment: A third hint might be: $f(x)>x$ for $x>0$, therefore $r,s<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $r$ and $s$ are distinct so it is possible to divide by $r-s$.

So, with the two values given, write:

$$ar^2+br+c=s$$$$as^2+bs+c=r$$

Now, if we subtract the second from the first we obtain:
$$a(r^2-s^2)+b(r-s)=s-r$$or $$a(r+s)+b=-1$$

Then I did $r$ times the first less $s$ times the second (note that $p(r)q(s)-p(s)q(r)$ will always have a factor $r-s$)

This left $$a(r^3-s^3)+b(r^2-s^2)+c(r-s)=0$$ or $$a(r^2+rs+s^2)+b(r+s)+c=0$$

Now I have two independent equations involving the terms of the arithmetic progression, and I want to simplify these as much as possible. First I put $r+s=t$ so that $r^2+rs+s^2=t^2-2017$ and $b+1=-at$

And that is probably far too much already done, but I got into it ...